# Facing issue in binding data in edit mode with Knockout.js

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have developed an application with ASP.Net MVC5 and KnockoutJS. In create mode I have successfully bind data but in edit mode I am facing a problem in data populating.I can getting the data using ajax call and it is returning the data in desired format but where it is complex object binding it is not binding properly.
My full code is written in the below link. Please suggest.

https://jsfiddle.net/9qget54a/

```
if (ruleId == ''|| ruleId==null)
        {

            self.rule = new ruleMetaData();
        }
        else
        {
            ajaxRequest("GET", baseUrl + controller + "GetRuleModelData/?ruleId=" + ruleId)
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                self.rule=new prepareRuleData(data);

                //self.rule = ruleMetaData;
            });
            //self.rule=ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
            console.log(self.rule);
        }
```

Comment: What specific issue are you facing?

Comment: controls are not populating with existing data @gkb